# Unable to pull data for todays date (where statements worked on other tables)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to pull data for today's date in the timestamp column only. The 'where' statement I am using worked for my other table, but this is still pulling old data. I have been trying a bunch of other methods but I think they may not be working because of the timestamp data and not just the date.

```
select column1,
       tf.order_number,
       column3,
       timestamp_est,
       column5 as station
from wms.transition_fact tf
join order_dim od
on od.order_number = tf.order_number
where timestamp_est <= GETDATE()
and to_state in ('picking', 'picked', 'pouching', 'pouch_printing_configured', 'checking', 'checked', 'packing', 'packed')
and associate_name is not null
order by 1, 4 asc
```

Comment: Does Postgres support `getdate()`?

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-current_date/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for your `where` clause:

```sql
where timestamp_est >= current_date and timestamp_est < (current_date + 1)
```

or shorter and clearer (but defeats an index on `timestamp_est` if any):

```sql
where timestamp_est::date = current_date
```

Comment: This works—thank you. I'll accept it when it allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want today's date in Postgres, I would expect:

```
timestamp_est >= CURRENT_DATE and
timestamp_est < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 DAY'
```